# Is it possible to control microphone gain in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-recording

I feel like I have searched and tried every audio package out there, but can't find a way to control the microphone gain. I'm building a recording app and theres a big issue when it comes to the volume of the recorded sounds. I don't want to increase the output volume, I want to increase the input volume.

If I understand it correctly, the iOS native API is the [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616546-setinputgain). I found [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_session) that I thought would enable this control, but doesn't seem to offer this functionality. Do I need to write some bridge code to deal with the native APIs for this or is it not even possible?

Comment: Is it neccessary for you to retrieve the hardware microphone gain? I'm not quite sure if this can be retrieved / modified. Can you just filter it inside your app?

Comment: Well it seems possible for other apps? But I guess I will have to try and write my own custom code and see if it's possible to access the native iOS/Android APIs. I mean according to threads on the internet and my own experience, audio input/output seems pretty bad in general in Flutter apps, so I don't know if I can use Flutter for this use case anyway.

Comment: I see. How do you know whether an app reduces the microphone gain via hardware and not via software? I'm not into audio engineering or such thing but from my understanding in most cases it is probably enought to handle the gain volume inside your code and not explicitly via hardware?